# Entity Framework - can't find/connect to localdb from within my project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, localdb

I'm following this guide:

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

My project is named WebApplication1. I have installed Entity Framework via nuget.

I have a class called **LoyaltyUsersContext.cs**:

```
namespace WebApplication1.DAL
{
public class LoyaltyUsersContext : DbContext
{
    public LoyaltyUsersContext() : base("LoyaltyUsersContext")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<LoyaltyUser> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

}

I have added the following value to my  in **web.config**:

```
<add name="LoyaltyUsersContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Webapplication1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

However, when I go to Server Explorer > Add Connection (MiscroSoft SQL Server, localdb doesn't show up under Server name - there aren't anything. There's also a "LoyaltyUsersContext(WebApplication1) under Data Connections, but I get an error when I try to refresh it.

[image]

[image]

Any idea why I can't seem to connect to localdb? I'm hoping it's just a connection string error or something.

Comment: The error you posted here **always** has an associated event log message telling you the *exact* reason that an automatic instance can't be created.  What do your event log messages say the problem is?

Comment: Hi @Claies, where can I find that event log?

Comment: In the windows Administrative Control Panel?

Comment: Okay, I'm looking at Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application. Is that correct? The only Warning in the last hour is this: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: WebApplication1.DAL.LoyaltyUser: : EntityType 'LoyaltyUser' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. Users: EntityType: EntitySet 'Users' is based on type 'LoyaltyUser' that has no keys defined.,

Comment: EntityType 'LoyaltyUser' has no key defined - then define your key using the [Key] Data annotation or .HasKey() Fluent API mapping.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I added [Key] to the id attribute: `[Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }` but I still can't refresh any of my db connections. I think it might be a configuration issue. Do you see anything wrong in my original post?

Comment: well, this was one error. what does your log file show? its hard to tell the error without seeing your POCO classes, your DB call, or your provider entry.

Comment: Are you seeding data like the tutorial?